# Can perl delete multiple lines in a file?

Tags: perl

I have been informed that I can use perl to remove lines from a text file I have. However, I have very brief experience of perl.

I need to match a number in my text file, obtained from a second file, and delete that line and the next 2 after it from the first file, and then skip to the next matched number and so on. The number I am trying to match will fall within a range. Is this possible? Or would it be easier to include the numbers to match, rather than in a second file, in the actual script such as under a -

```
__DATA__
23-28
47-55
108-139
etc
```

sort of format?

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Many thanks in advance.

*Sorry I probably should have started with what I have done, I have tried this code:"

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl 

use strict; 
use warnings; 

my $number = <DATA>; 

open( FILE, "<MGE.txt" ); 
my @LINES = <FILE>; 
foreach my $LINE ( @LINES ) { 
    print FILE $LINE unless ( $LINE =~ m/$data/ ); 
} 
close( FILE ); 
}
__DATA__
34163-51525
80765-83026
137322-138041
141474-142274
315945-318143
etc...
```

However, I receive -

```
Global symbol $data requires explicit package name.
```

Comment: That error means you haven't declared `$data`. Did you mean `my $data = <DATA>;` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some problems with your attempt:

1. `FILE` is only open for reading, so you won't be able to `print` to it.
2. After slurping in all of the lines `FILE` will be at the end of the file.

A solution along your original code:

```
open(FILE, "<", "MGE.txt") or die "open read failed: $!";
my @LINES = <FILE>;
# reopen FILE for writing
open(FILE, ">", "MGE.txt") or die "open write failed: $!"
for my $LINE (@LINES) {
  print FILE $LINE if ...;
}
close(FILE);
```

Another standard approach is to use the `Tie::File` module - http://perldoc.perl.org/Tie/File.html